# how to add space after the text overflow ellipsis dots(...) and text

Tags: html, css

hi i am using truncate function to cut off my text .

i can get the expected result but needs some styling , not sure how to do it .

current output is :

...texttext

expected output is:

... texttext

i need to add space after those 3 dots before the text. can anyone help with this

i am using  the following code,

```
   .title{
     font-size: 8pt;
     direction: rtl;
     -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-indent:2px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this could be achieved using pure CSS. However, you could apply some javascript logic to check and put a class like follows:

```js
var p = document.querySelector(".title");

if (p.scrollWidth > p.offsetWidth) p.classList.add("ellipsis");

while (p.scrollWidth > p.offsetWidth) {
  p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
}
```

```css
p {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  /* BOTH of the following are required for text-overflow */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ellipsis:after {
  content: " ... "
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class="title">
    Testing overflow: look at me ! Testing overflow: look at me !Testing overflow: look at me !
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `text-indent:2px;` your issue will be fixed